# how to have child's for multiple named views in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have read documentations on 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views
about multiple named views but I need to change each view with different states for example I want to have contacts and settings view in the filters ui-view, I think the answer is defining childs for each ui-view but I haven't found anything on the documentation about how to define childs for these ui-views, can someone tell me if this is possible?

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

in the controllers:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('report', {
    views: {
      'filters': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'tabledata': {},
      'graph': {},
    }
  })
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve. The code you pasted does not explain your question.

Comment: @GaneshKumar  I want to have 3 different parts in my page that I want to update their content and sometimes completely change their template, so I have come to the solution that I need to define childs for ui-views but how should I do that?see whats app web for instance